# Solve $u_x+u_t=f(x,t)$ in terms of $f$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the first order PDE $u_x+u_t=f(x,t)$, where $f$ is some function. And I want to write $u$ in terms of $f$. I'm thinking of the characteristic method.  But I couldn't find a nice way to write the solution to $\frac {dx}{1}=\frac{du}{f}$ because we are working on arbitrary $f$. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thus is a linear inhomogeneous PDE. The associated homogeneous PDE is
$$u_x+u_t =0$$
and has the general solution $$u(x,t)=\phi(x-t).$$
In order to find a particular solution, one could use [Duhamel's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duhamel%27s_principle). For that we need a solution $P^s f(x,t)$ of the homogeneous equation, satisfying
$$ P^sf(x,s)=f(x,s).$$
It turns out that
$P^s f(x,t)=f(x-t+s,s)$.
A particular solution is then
$$ \int_0 ^t f(x-t+s,s) \mathrm{d} s,$$
and the general solution is
$$ u(x,t)=\phi(x-t)+\int_0^t f(x-t+s,s) \mathrm{d} s$$
where $\phi$ is an arbitrary function.